# get xml data by jquery.ajax

Tags: asp.net, xml, jquery, xmlhttprequest

Script

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "Default.aspx?cmd=Setting",
    success: parseXml
  });

function parseXml(xml)
{
   alert(xml);//show Full XML File
  //find every Tutorial and print the author
  $(xml).find("Tutorial").each(function()
  {
    $("#a").append($(this).attr("author") + "<br />");
  });
 }
```

HTML

```
<div id="a"></div>
```

Code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request["cmd"] == "Setting")
    {
        string k=@"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
        <RecentTutorials>
        <Tutorial author='The Reddest'>
        <Title>Silverlight and the Netflix API</Title>
        <Categories>
              <Category>Tutorials</Category>
              <Category>Silverlight 2.0</Category>
              <Category>Silverlight</Category>
              <Category>C#</Category>
              <Category>XAML</Category>
        </Categories>
        <Date>1/13/2009</Date>
        </Tutorial>
        </RecentTutorials>";

          Response.Write(k );
          Response.End();
    }
}
```

I am a beginner.

This doesn't work.

while alert(xml) show xml File.

Comment: Please define "doesn't work".

Comment: Have you tried `alert(xml);` inside `parseXml`

Comment: show xml but does not append to div

Answer (score 1):

Set the proper content type on your server in order to have jQuery automatically parse the XML:

```
Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
Response.Write(k);
Response.End();
```

Additionally you could set `dataType: 'xml'` but that's not necessary if your server is properly configured to send the correct content type.

Here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gKMJW/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing the dataType to xml: `dataType: 'xml'`

Comment: To be consequent one should use additionally `Response.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";` in the server code