# Ajax response receiving as XML

Tags: php, jquery

I'm getting all ajax responses as XML only. When i implement them, it worked fine(i got the responses as HTML). Is there any reason that we are receiving the responses as XML by default? I think something has been changed recently. But i couldn't able to corner the change. Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

***NOTE:** Please note that I'm using jQuery for AJAX.*

[image]

Here is the code i'm using in one of the place in my site (in all the places i'm using in the same manner and it is coming in XML only, as shown in the screenshot)

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ajax_contests_submissions_more&popup=yes",
        dataType:"html",
        data: 'last_pos='+queryPos, 
        cache: false,

        error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('sorry, we were unable to process your request. please try again later'); 
        },          

        success: function(html)
        { 
        }   
    });
```

Please check this image which shows that browser will not guess the XHTML as XML as per **@dystroy**'s comment.

[image: Another AJAX response]

Comment: Where are you getting the responses from ? Do you mean you receive XML or do you mean the mime-type in the response header is XML ?

Comment: Can you put some code samples?

Comment: @Udhay if possible post your code through which ur generating that response

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288173/get-xml-data-by-jquery-ajax

Comment: @Udhay Show us the ajax calling code, and the server code. You've most likely omitted the mime response type.

Comment: If you don't set the mime-type server side, the browser tries to guess the type. What you show seems to be XHTML (thus XML).

Comment: @dystroy: If you send an XHTML also, it will be received as HTML only. I don't think that the browser will "**Guess**" the response ;)

Answer (score 0):

AJAX replies tries to parse the response as XML. So you can grab either XML or the raw text.

See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_response.asp)

Comment: Since i am using jQuery, i should get it as raw text by default. But it sucks.